# Can someone explain about the attendance record in "Another"

Tags: another

In 1996, Mami Asakura was the extra student. She was also a student of 1993 (and she died that year). When she joins Yomiyama Junior High, Her name from the 1993 record disappears and everyone who knew her, loses their memory about her. After she disappeared, her name from 1996 record gets erased and it reappears in the 1993 record.  **Am I correct?**

**Also, will her friends remember that she was in 1993?**

**How did chibiki identify that Mami Asakura was the deceased if a person's memories are altered?**

Comment: If i remember correctly it's when the Catastrophe ends (either the Extra dies or all the deaths have occurred) all the records and memories are restored. i would assume Chibiki noticed a discrepancy (a student who died who cane back 3 years later) but wasn't able to confirm it until Mei saw the colour of death around her in the photo (i think that was then they realized that they could use Mei to id the Extra by looking for the person who had the colour of death)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. After the calamity ends, the records are restored (even photographs), and some (maybe all, maybe none) of the memories.

Tatsuji keeps careful records of all classes 3-3. Since he reveals the truth about Mami in 1998, the data was already restored.

It is not shown, but he probably also tracks the deaths.

It is not shown if Tatsuji's memories were erased or not.  We know that the records both written and graphical (photographs) are edited and the extra removed - and later repositioned - name and image. But the memory of the calamity is not erased. People know that deaths occured. For someone tracking the calamity for as long as Tetsuji, and that know of the phenomena around the extra's records could spot a blank where something **should** be there. The calamity does not prevent discovery of the extra through sleuthing.

He could restore the information by crossing data from the records. The "extra" would be evident because there is no enrollment papers, no admission exam score, etc. Also the duplicate name.

As people remembering, it is blurry. People involved in a calamity class usually die or won't want to remember or keep themselves involved with the school.

So probably when Mami returned (or anyone else, for that matter) nobody that once knew her in life was there to remember.

Comment: So when the extra joins class 9, the name gets added to the record and when the extra dies, it's removed. Tatsuji identifies this. Is that correct

Comment: @AdityaDev it is class 3-3, not nine. They tried to rename it several times, but to no avail.